# Movie about a fantasy world in which a human is brought to train in martial arts for a mission/quest

Tags: story-identification

I was flipping though the channels and found this movie where a kid in his early 20's was brought to a fantasy world to do some sort of mission/quest. They had him train with some martial arts guy for a bit to get stronger. The kid had a companion named "Monkey" who looked like a human monkey with a pole that he did martial arts with and He was HOT! I also remember an Asian girl that the main guy had a crush on. She rode up to and down from the city in the sky. I think was made in the 90s.

Please help. Can you tell me what movie this is?

Answer (score 10):

Sounds a lot like [The Forbidden Kingdom](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/The_Forbidden_Kingdom). Jet Li plays both the Monkey King and the Silent Monk; the Monkey King casts his magic staff away and the main protagonist (Jason Tripitikas, played by Michael Angarano) has to return it to him. On the journey, he learns martial arts from Jackie Chan (as "Lu Yan, the Drunken Immortal") and Liu Yifei (as "Golden Sparrow", a young woman who falls in love with the protagonist.)

Comment: no it's not that although that looks like a really good movie to see :)

Comment: Any more details?

Comment: You might browse through [this Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_media_adaptations_of_Journey_to_the_West), as there are just enough elements in your description to make me suspect it probably belongs on that list.

Comment: no I tried that but I will try again. lets see city in sky where the guys there controled every thing that went on. the gril that rode on the cloud worked for them I think.

Answer (score 5):

Might be "[The forbidden Kingdom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0865556/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_27)" (The pole fighting Monkey King only appears at the end of the movie):

> An American teenager who is obsessed with Hong Kong cinema and kung-fu
>   classics makes an extraordinary discovery in a Chinatown pawnshop: the
>   legendary stick weapon of the Chinese sage and warrior, the Monkey
>   King. With the lost relic in hand, the teenager unexpectedly finds
>   himself traveling back to ancient China to join a crew of warriors
>   from martial arts lore on a dangerous quest to free the imprisoned
>   Monkey King.

Comment: No it's not that but it is similer with more fantacy

Answer (score 4):

Might be a made for TV movie, "The Lost Empire"

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0198779/

An American writer has to save the story of the Monkey King from being erased by Confucious for not being "Traditional".

Comment: no It's not that I cheeked